# how to populate a multiple email field with data in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  an input text that contains a multiple emails, I used [this plugin](https://github.com/Alplob/multiple-emails.js/tree/master)
It's working fine when I type emails into that field.

the problem now when I saved the form and try to edit it the values are not displayed into that field ..

How to display emails into that field using javascript or jquery ?

This is the jquery code to show the emails field :

```
 $('#id_emails').multiple_emails();
```

I tried to change the value of that field like this :

```
$('.multiple_emails-input').val({{ emails|safe }});
```

this what's in HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="multiple_emails-input text-left">
r@gmail.com
ra@gmail.com
r2h@gmail.com
</input>
```

where `{{emails}}` is the emails list returned by the server, but nothing is shown

could somebody help me on this ?

Comment: Check the HTML output first to make sure the val() parameter actually gets populated, then check if val('anything') works fine.

Comment: I have tried that see update .. but it's not working

Comment: OK, can you change the input fields to <input/> format (no closing tag)

Comment: or try this: $('.multiple_emails-input').val("{{ emails|safe }}");

Comment: by HTML output I meant how exactly the val is being populated with the {{server side var}} content

Comment: the field is  generated from the server side, I can't remove `</input>` tag,  $('.multiple_emails-input').val("{{ emails|safe }}") is not working either

Comment: I'd try var emails = '{{emails|safe}}'; console.log(emails); $('.multiple_emails-input').val(emails); to be able to debug it. Also I assume that code is inside document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this plugin hasn't any API to reset and repopulate list, so we can try to emulate user actions (although it is not a nice way).

For example:

```
//remove all items
$('.multiple_emails-email .glyphicon-remove').click();

//add new item:
$('.multiple_emails-input').val('test@new.email').blur();
$('.multiple_emails-input').val('test@new.email').blur(); //for some reason this 
//must be called twice when adding first new item (I don't know why)
//second item:
$('.multiple_emails-input').val('one@more.email').blur();
```

This code works on the [demo-page](http://alplob.github.io/multiple-emails.js/).

Comment: Thanks a lot :D It works like a charm !!! 
You saved my day thank you :)